# why im getting error "404 NOT FOUND" when adding HttpModule in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, 404, http-module, page-not-found

I developed a `httpmodule` that inherits from `IHttpModule` to use "Session_Start" event, add the output DLL to GAC and adds the "add" tag into web.config in "modules" section.

All things seem to be ok but when I go to my website.  I got this message `"404 NOT FOUND"` but I can go to `"View All Site Content"` on my site.

Why this happening?

Comment: what does your module do ?

Comment: it's gonna use some events like "Session_Start" or "Session_End"

Comment: ok, but what are doing into these events ?

Comment: It seems inside that module code you are accessing some objects that's doesn't exists. Have you tried debugging your module code?